# hook for db insert function on custom table

Tags: 7, database

Is there any hook on `db_insert` function on a custom table?

```
db_insert('projects')
  ->fields(array(
    'title' => $title,
    'p_key' => $projectkey,
  ))->execute();
```

Comment: Not enough info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no hook invoked for `db_insert`.

If you have a custom table, though, you're probably controlling the insert code yourself, in which case you can invoke your own:

```
db_insert()->(...);
module_invoke_all('mymodule_foo_insert', $some_contextual_data);
```

Comment: Yeah, I had to look this to remind myself.  `InsertQuery` doesn't implement `QueryAlterableInterface`, so `hook_query_alter()` doesn't get called.